# Do I need a resistor in circuit when charging capacitors?

Tags: capacitor, resistors, circuit-breaker

I want to charge a group of capacitors whose total equivalent capacitance is \$ 705 \:\mu F\$ and whose equivalent series resistance is on the order of \$10^{-2} \:\Omega\$. I am trying to charge them with a 120 VAC wall socket, a (not isolation) transformer to step up to 240 VAC, and a bridge rectifier.

I know that initially, the capacitors act like a short circuit, and would draw a very high current. The peak of 240 VAC is about 340 V, so I calculated the peak current drawn on the secondary side (with only the ESR limiting it) as 34,000 A. And, since the primary has half the voltage, it would have double the current. This makes me worried about causing damage to wiring in my house and/or tripping the breaker. However, in this [instructable](https://www.instructables.com/How-to-Make-a-Railgun/), they don't add any resistor into the charging circuit, which makes me think that the current draw is for such a tiny amount of time that it doesn't cause any harm (my capacitors and transformers are not the exact same as those in this instructable). I calculated the time constant to be about \$705 * 10^{-8}\:s\$, which is so small that I think it might be ok.

Will the capacitors charge quick enough not to cause any harm? Or do I need to find a resistor to add to the circuit? If so, does the resistor actually have to be rated for 340V or can I get away with a smaller one since it'll only be for a short time?

Comment: I saw a couple of things in the instructable that made me shudder.

Comment: Yeah, I am hoping to do it safer than they did it

Comment: Work with an isolated DC voltage and design a voltage boost converter to raise the voltage on the capacitors efficiently and safely without incurring massive inrush currents. I design capacitor charging power supplies so I'm bound to say that of course.

Comment: that intructable makes a linear motor, not a railgun.

Comment: You don’t need a resistor if you connect cap through SCR and trigger it right after zero cross.

Answer (score 2):

"Will the capacitors charge quick enough not to cause any harm?"

What do you mean by "not cause any harm"? very high peak currents for a short period may or may not cause damage to the components themselves (either immediately or over time), but to be avoided, at least because they can cause interference to some other equipment.

"Or do I need to find a resistor to add to the circuit?"

For reasons given above, you need SOME way to limit the instantaneous current, you don't just connect a voltage source to a cap, where both have extremely low series resistance. It doesn't have to be a resistor. You could (as suggested above) try to ramp the current up. There are non-linear devices designed specifically to limit inrush current. You could use a simple series resistor. It depends on design requirements.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on which phase of the network the capacitor begins to charge. The worst case is peak values, meaning that all the current will be applied to the ESR of said capacitor. In turn, this ESR value will degrade dramatically even after the first charge if said capacitor survives. It could explode!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a resistor in series after the rectifier bridge to charge the capacitor initially and later bypass using relays which is commonly used.
Other way is to use solid state static relays which can be also used in series ( connected to gnd) with the capacitor as per attached image..
[image]

Comment: Harsha Infineon - Hi, As you're new here, please see the [tour] & [help] for the main site rules. || Please note that if a post copies or adapts content (e.g. text, image, photo etc.) from elsewhere, that content [must be correctly referenced](/help/referencing). As a minimum, for online material, the *original* source webpage / PDF / video etc. should be named & linked (see that rule about references for books / articles etc.). Therefore please [edit] your answer to name & link the original source(s) used for that image (and remember it's your responsibility to do that in future). Thanks.

Comment: (continued) Also, since you seem to be representing Infineon, and since I expect your image comes from their material, you are effectively promoting them. So please see [this site rule on promotions](/help/promotion). You must include a disclosure of your association with Infineon inside any question or answer where you use, mention, or even hint at anything related to Infineon or associated companies, products, websites etc. Also be careful not to *only* be seen to promote their products, as excessive promotion can be interpreted as spam. Thanks.